# Javascript length variable displaying zero

Tags: javascript, arrays

can you please look at the image below and let me know what would lead to this?
The console shows that the variable playIcons has 3 items in it's array.
then I'm declaring x = playIcons.length. (FYI - I tested it with several other variable names to make sure that the name wasn't causing the issue.)
However x generates as zero, but when I put playIcons.length I receive the correct total. (3).  Also, FYI, this is global.(not inside of a function)

Please let me know what leads to this so I can avoid it going forward.[image]

Comment: Please see: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a way to reproduce your problem, so I offer this working example as a counterexample and a guide to correct usage.

```js
let playIcons = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-play");
let x = playIcons.length;
console.log('x is', x);
```

```html
<div class="fa-play">A</div>
<div class="fa-play">B</div>
<div class="fa-play">C</div>
```

Comment: This mirrors the code in the question. I added your console.log suggestion and received x is 0. IHowever, it should be 3. Thanks for trying to assist though.

Comment: Go ahead and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72565298/edit) your question to add the snippet that reproduces the problem then, please.

Answer (score 0):

We certainly can't know what *is* causing this, because you haven't provided a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  But if the question is what *could* cause this...

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is a *live* collection of elements and *is automatically updated* when the underlying DOM changes.  So `playIcons` *may have changed* between the time you first measured it's length and the time you next measured its length.

For example:

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('live');
let x = coll.length;
console.log('x: ', x);

let el = document.createElement('span');
el.classList.add('live');
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(el);

// Note: coll was never re-assigned or modified by me
let y = coll.length;
console.log('y: ', y);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure about your comment about an example  not being provided when the code is in the question. However. No all 3 play icons are still being displayed however X is showing as zero. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: @madQuestions: Because a picture of part of the code is not a [mcve].  Even the picture suggests there are at least 56 lines of JavaScript code which could be doing literally anything.  If you can provide an actual runnable example then you can get a more specific answer.